# I see a tendency of not upgrading from a Live Disk (avoided)?

Tags: discussion

As far as I know upgrading a distribution from DVD or USB is possible and I see a lot of failed upgrades ( or got the impression ) because the upgrade was interrupted. This method can leave those variables out and yield more successful upgrades.

Comment: IMO it is due to the complexity of upgrading via USB vs a simple `do-relese-uprade` command. I have never upgraded by a USB so I can't say much more. Why is it safer? If the upgrade was interrupted, surly that is user error.

Comment: Couple of off-topic votes on this. I consider this completely on-topic for meta. It's a technical discussion over why a solution isn't used more often on the main site.

Comment: This is *probably* what I'd naturally do without looking if recovery mode didn't work. What is the alternative people are suggesting when an upgrade breaks? Can you show us some examples?

Comment: Could you clarify your title please? The double negative you currently have would mean that you are asking why upgrading from a disk *is* often recommended. *isn't* + *not often* = *is often*. I think you mean *Why isn't upgrading from a disk recommended more often* but I'm not sure.

Comment: What is the meaning of AFAIK?

Comment: @CristianaNicolae AFAIK: As Far As I Know

Comment: So, what you want us to do as community?

Comment: @ThomasWard But even there you can have a correct installation. And then the user can update as they wish to. I think.